# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 50 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json, ajax

when i use....

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

i get an error => "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 50 of the JSON data"

this is my JSON data from a php script

```
{"results":[{"oldID":5,"oldMain":"News papers"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":3,"oldMain":"Construction"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":2,"oldMain":"Banking Files"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":1,"oldMain":"Technologies"}]}
```

Can some please help?.... Thanks

Comment: your JSON is not valid

Comment: You ask the JSON provider to fix it. Nothing you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not a valid json, you must wrap it in array. the valid json is like this

```
[{
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 5,
        "oldMain": "News papers"
    }]
}, {
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 3,
        "oldMain": "Construction"
    }]
}, {
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 2,
        "oldMain": "Banking Files"
    }]
}, {
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 1,
        "oldMain": "Technologies"
    }]
}]
```

take a look at the bracket **[ ]** at the start and the end of string , and the **,** to split the object.

this some online json linter [here](https://jsonlint.com/) to check if your json is valid.

Answer (score 9):

A little bit late to the party, but @igniz87 and @Benjamin James Kippax's answers open your website to **security issues**, and it is so **dangerous** to follow their example.
As Owasp reads,

```
ALWAYS RETURN JSON WITH AN OBJECT ON THE OUTSIDE
```

Hence, so as to be a layer protected from the barbarism of hackers, you need to ALWAYS have the outside primitive be an object for JSON strings. As you can clearly see, the mentioned people's answers do not follow this crucial security rule.

Owasp, moreover, brings an example and says that a JSON like the following is `EXPLOITABLE`:

```
[{"object": "inside an array"}]
```

Yet, the following JSONs are not,

```
{"object": "not inside an array"}
{"result": [{"object": "inside an array"}]}
```

You need to remove the duplicate key element and change it in the following way so you will have an object on the outside.

```
{
"results": [{
    "oldID": 5,
    "oldMain": "News papers"
}],
"resultss": [{
    "oldID": 3,
    "oldMain": "Construction"
}]}
```

Here, actually you should have brought you php code, as the problem is with that php code which is sending the JSON. When you want to send the JSON try to make an array of your data. I do the following way.

```
        $data = [];
        foreach ($results as $res) {
            $t = [];
            $t['oldID'] = $res['oldID'];
            $t['oldMain'] = $res['oldMain'];
            $data[] = $t;
        }
        echo json_encode(['results' => $data]);
```

You'd better send your php code which is lacking here. My php script does not contain all of your code, but it gives you idea how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same problem for the past several years.
Sometimes the problem is not related to invalid JSON .. like me now.. the problem is that I must use `stringify` before `JSON.parse`

```
var db = JSON.stringify(data);
var db = JSON.parse(db);
```

And sometimes in php you must use `json_encode($data)` correctly.

And sometimes your JSON is not valid ( [Online JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) )

Comment: If you don't have a JSON string in the first place, you don't need `JSON.parse`. It makes no sense to convert an object to JSON, just so you can convert it back to an object.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is not valid. If it is possible, you can update the JSON as following

```
{
"results": [{
    "oldID": 5,
    "oldMain": "News papers"
}],
"resultss": [{
    "oldID": 3,
    "oldMain": "Construction"
}]}
```

And also JSON should not contain duplicate key elements. Also you can club the JSON to JSONArray like this

```
[{
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 5,
        "oldMain": "News papers"
    }]
},
{
    "results": [{
        "oldID": 3,
        "oldMain": "Construction"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid.

Your code;

```
{"results":[{"oldID":5,"oldMain":"News papers"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":3,"oldMain":"Construction"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":2,"oldMain":"Banking Files"}]}{"results":[{"oldID":1,"oldMain":"Technologies"}]}
```

Your code validated;

```
[{"results":[{"oldID":5,"oldMain":"News papers"}]},
{"results":[{"oldID":3,"oldMain":"Construction"}]},
{"results":[{"oldID":2,"oldMain":"Banking Files"}]},
{"results":[{"oldID":1,"oldMain":"Technologies"}]}]
```

The problem is that you had multiple JSON root elements. These also weren't comma separated. They also need wrapping in [], which will turn it into an object. If you don't want to wrap your response in [], you can return the string without the [] and instead do this;

```
JSON.parse('['+yourreponse+']') which will parse the JSON correctly.
```

Answer (score -1):

Above answer are correct i.e. your json syntax is incorrect. Correcting your syntax would solved the problem (as suggested)

My case was a little different. I was returning json in response to ajax calls. Those jsons where returned by php using a if else construct. Where I mistakenly omitted one else;

```
if (!empty($_GET['arg1']))
  echo getTrainings($filter, 'arg1');
elseif (!empty($_GET['arg2']))
  echo getTrainings($filter, 'arg2');
if (empty($_GET['arg3']))
  echo getTrainings($filter, 'arg3');
elseif (empty($_GET['arg4']))
  echo getTrainings($filter, 'arg4');
```

So in fact two json where being returned instead of one, that caused problem for $.parseJSON(result);

```
var par = $.parseJSON(result);
```